# The TextInput clear and keyboard close every time i type(React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Every time i type at Input in my app the text disappear and keyboard close, i searched forms to solve this but there is not many things, actually nothing that help me.

Then this is my code, the useState:

```
  const [nameRoom, setNameRoom] = useState('');
```

The textInput:

```
      <TextInput
      style={styles.modalTextInput}
      onChangeText={(txt) => setNameRoom(txt)}
       value={nameRoom}
      />
```

I think that my code is ok, but i think that there is another thing on my full code that is cause of the problem

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have here, you'll have to include a [mre] to allow any insight into the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.modalTextInput}
  onChangeText={setNameRoom}
   value={nameRoom}
/>
```

Instead of excecute setNameRoom() in onChangeText just call it. You can see detailed example and explanation on [react native doc.](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput)

Comment: This is simply another way of writing the code in the question, it won't change the behavior at all.

Answer (score 1):

The text was disappearing e keyboard was closing because the `useState` was out of function that the `<TextInput/>` was there.

then instead:

```
//..
      const [nameRoom, setNameRoom] = useState('');
//...
function getInput(){
      <TextInput
      style={styles.modalTextInput}
      onChangeText={(txt) => setNameRoom(txt)}
       value={nameRoom}
      />
}
```

Should be:

```
//...
function getInput(){
const [nameRoom, setNameRoom] = useState('');
      <TextInput
      style={styles.modalTextInput}
      onChangeText={(txt) => setNameRoom(txt)}
       value={nameRoom}
      />
}
```